# How do I use <a> anchor elements in Flutter web?

Tags: html, flutter, dart, flutter-web

#### Current setup (using `launch`)

I want to use links in my Flutter web app and currently do it like this (using the [`url_launcher` package](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)):

```dart
return MouseRegion(
  cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      launch('https://creativemaybeno.dev');
    },
    child: const Text(
      'my amazing link',
      style: TextStyle(
        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

##### What works using `launch`

There are three things that this code snippet does right:

- Fully works on mobile
- Shows click cursor on hover on web
- Opens the link on web in *most cases*

##### What does *not* work using `launch`

However, there are a number of issues I have with this on web compared to using an `<a>` anchor element in regular HTML:

- Link preview is not shown in the bottom-left corner of the browser.
  This is what it looks like on **regular HTML** pages:

[image: screenshot]

- Links seem to be opening *more slowly* than the ones in regular web apps
- Safari blocks my links completely ("blocked a pop-up")

Especially the links not working on Safari as well as the link preview not showing I *really* need to get resolved in order to have a smooth web experience. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution

The [`url_launcher` package](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) actually has a built-in solution for this that not many are aware of: the [link library](https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/link/link-library.html). This library provides a [`Link` widget](https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/link/Link-class.html) that fixes all of the mentioned problems:

- Shows link preview on hover (by inserting an `<a>` element on web).
- Works on all browsers (not blocked as a popup, never).
- Opens as fast as on regular HTML pages.
- Also works on mobile by default.

### Usage

The `Link` widget can be used like this:

```dart
return MouseRegion(
  cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
  child: Link(
    uri: Uri.parse('https://creativemaybeno.dev'),
    target: LinkTarget.blank,
    builder: (context, followLink) {
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: followLink,
        child: const Text(
          'my amazing link',
          style: TextStyle(
            decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
            // The default link color according to the HTML living standard.
            // See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#phrasing-content-3,
            // which defines :link { color: #0000EE; }.
            color: Color(0xff0000ee),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

As you can see, you simply need to specify the `uri` that should be opened on tap as well as the `target` which defines *how* the link is opened. *Read through [the docs to learn more](https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher_platform_interface/latest/link/LinkTarget-class.html)*.

Now, the `Link` widget provides you with a `builder` that passes a `followLink` callback. You simply call this upon your desired on tap action (pass it to a `GestureDetector` for example).
You do not have to use a `Text` widget as a child - you can actually use **anything**, e.g. a button.

Just note that the `<a>` anchor preview will be shown on hover of the *whole area* taken up by the child widget. So try to not make the button / child very large :)